# server sent events: how to address client

Tags: javascript, php, server-sent-events

I read this about server sent events:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events
My question is how to address a specific client. Is this possible or is a server sent event just a broadcast being received by all clients currently notified?

Comment: Please clarify your question, it is too broad: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: one way is to actually have a slightly different channel that each client subscribes to, with some sort of unique identifer on the querystring. Or you could store stuff in the session and then have logic to send different events to different clients depending on their session data

Comment: Hallo ADyson, thanks for this hints, they will be useful. Do I understand you correctly: There is no way to address a client directly but one has to use the data (different events)? The events are transmitted to all clients and each client has to filter based on, e. g., event?